# Access all controllers of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which requires two controllers and has another controller specified with the `controller` property, `TreeNodeController`.

```
.directive('uiTreeNode', function () {
    return {
      require: ['^uiTreeNodes', '^uiTree'],
      controller: 'TreeNodeController',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) { ... }
    };
  });
```

My question is how can I access the `TreeNodeController` from the `link` method?

When I log the `controllers` parameter, it is an array containing only the `uiTreeNodes` and `uiTree` controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the directive's controller, you have to require it too. Use the directive name (not the controller name) in the require array.

```
.directive('uiTreeNode', function () {
    return {
       require: ['^uiTreeNodes', '^uiTree', 'uiTreeNode'],
       controller: 'TreeNodeController',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) { 
          var treeNodeCtrl = controllers[2];
       }
    };
 });
```

If you're using `controllerAs` syntax, the controller is also on the scope:

```
.directive('uiTreeNode', function () {
    return {
        require: ['^uiTreeNodes', '^uiTree'],
        controller: 'TreeNodeController',
        controllerAs: 'view',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) { 
          var treeNodeCtrl = scope.view;
        }
};
```

Comment: In this case I'm not using the `controllerAs` syntax. Any ideas on how to access the controller without using this syntax?

Comment: @Voles See my edit. You can require the directive's controller by the directive name!